# Grid cell properties- J Index Flip

Tags: ocean, petrel

Is it necessary to flip the J index while exporting the properties (Perm, porosity) to an Ascii file outside the Petrel environment?

Comment: Hi Krishna, what are you trying to do with the properties after you've exported them? i.e. what will be importing them?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to upscale the static properties using an in-house research code and re-sample the upscaled properties back onto the fine grid in petrel for visualization. When reading the exported properties from Petrel, I found that the properties are not in the regular ijk order.

Comment: I assume when you say "to an Ascii file" you mean export using "Export object" as "ECLIPSE keywords (grid properties) (ASCII)"? On the dialog to pick the properties to export there is an "Advanced..." button that allows you to control the Petrel cell origin. What do you mean by "regular ijk order"? The IJK order of exported properties should be consistent with visualization (i.e what you see if you pick on a cell).

Comment: Hi Drew, I forgot to mention that I am working inside the Ocean environment. So, when I export the petrel grid properties through Ocean, I do not know if the J flip option is applied or not. I am aware of the procedure you have mentioned regarding exporting properties and in there the Advanced button, J flip is checked by default. This is where the IJK order is mixed up. I am not sure I am conveying the problem clearly.